# sql query to find non-mapping column values

Tags: sql, plsql

Difficult to put down in words, so assuming this example table:

```
| id | col1 | col2 | 
--------------------
| 1  |  aa  |  12  |
| 2  |  aa  |  12  |
| 3  |  bb  |  13  |
| 4  |  cc  |  13  |
```

I would like a query which selects rows 3 & 4 or even just the value 13

So something like checking this assumption: "all values of col2 which are the same should map one value of col1"

I've been checking by doing a 'group by' and row count for each column in separate queries and comparing, but it would be nice to be able to pick out offending rows

A query or pl/sql procedure would be fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get just "13":

```
select col2
from mytable
group by col2 having count(distinct col1) > 1;
```

To get the rows:

```
select * from mytable where col2 in
( select col2
  from mytable
  group by col2 having count(distinct col1) > 1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is col2 based on unique col1, this is it:

```
SELECT col2 FROM [table] GROUP BY col1 HAVING count(id) = 1;
```

If you want col2 based on a unique col1 and col2 value, the following should work:

```
SELECT col2 FROM [table] GROUP BY col1, col2 HAVING count(id) = 1;
```

Comment: accepted answer happens to fit better to my real table. Thanks anyway.